# Conditionals Inside Nested For Loops

Tags: loops, if-statement, terraform, conditional-statements

I am trying to figure out a way to skip the iteration of an inner `for` loop if a particular attribute does not exist - in this case `variables`. However, I am beginning to wonder if I am expecting too much from a declarative language.

This is my input:

```
locals {
  environments = {
    dev : {
      name: "development"
      variables : [
        {
          key: "GCP_PROJECT"
          value: "gcp-project-1"
        },
        {
          key: "ANOTHER_VAR"
          value: "some-value"
        }
      ]
    }
    prod : {
      name : "production"
      variables : [
        {
          key: "GCP_PROJECT"
          value: "gcp-project-2"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

`environments` is consumed here, which basically iterates through `variables` to convert and store it in a data structure that is easier to work with later on:

```
locals {
  variables = flatten([
    for k, env in local.environments : [
      for var, var in env.variables : { <--- Is there a way to skip an iteration if env.variables does not exist?
        key: var.key
        value: var.value
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```

This loop will output something similar to this:

```
variables = [
  {
    key   = "KEY"
    value = "VALUE"
  }
]
```

Which ultimately is used here:

```
resource "gitlab_project_variable" "variable" {
  for_each = {
    for i, v in local.variables : v.terraform_id => v
  }

  key   = each.value.key
  value = each.value.value
}
```

Comment: Why not just `flatten(local.environments.key.variables)` ?

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? Any errors?

Comment: No errors, but it will error if `variables` is missing during an iteration.

Comment: Sure @Paolo that will certainly work. I should have mentioned that there can be multiple "keys" under `environments` however, like "dev", "prod".

Comment: @Marcus So what is your actual variable? Clearly the one you provide does not represent your real use case.

Comment: Certainly @Marcin. I have edited the original post, the variable being very close to the original. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [lookup](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/lookup):

```
locals {
  variables = flatten([
    for k, env in local.environments : [
      for var, var in lookup(env, "variables", {}) : { 
        key: var.key
        value: var.value
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcin! That did it. Such an obvious solution too.

Answer (score 1):

I would typically recommend setting object attributes to `null` when you aren't using them so that the object type remains consistent in all cases, and then you can use comparison with `null` as the filter:

```
locals {
  variables = flatten([
    for k, env in local.environments : [
      for var, var in env.variables : { 
        key: var.key
        value: var.value
      }
    ]
    if env.variables != null
  ])
}
```

You could also set the inapplicable ones to be an empty list and then your expression would work without any extra conditions at all.

If you really do want to use inconsistent object types for your environment objects then it's not so clean to handle but you can still get something similar to the above by using [the `can` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/can) to detect when accessing the `variables` attribute would fail:

```
locals {
  variables = flatten([
    for k, env in local.environments : [
      for var, var in env.variables : { 
        key: var.key
        value: var.value
      }
    ]
    if can(env.variables)
  ])
}
```